# codeigniter add language flag in the end of url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I`m using Codeigniter 3.0.3
I need to add language flag in the end of the URL

and on loading any page
I need to check like this

```
// removing slash
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
// checking if it url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
// splitting $url on slashes
$this->_Url = explode('/', $url);

// checking if exists language
if(lang::Check(end($this->_Url))) unset($this->_Url[count($this->_Url) - 1]);
```

and after that I need to send `$this->_Url` to bootstrap and route this

also I need to create some how lang class with implementing database
to check if this flag is in database...

so how can I do this???

this is url which will type client

http://www.example.com/controller/function/value1/value2/value3/en

and as en is flag of English so the converted url must be

http://www.example.com/controller/function/value1/value2/value3

and en must add in session after check
with key `lang_key`

Comment: can you give an example of original url and want to convert url

Comment: I update my real post with example links...

Comment: Can anyone help me????

Answer (score 0):

```
function($value1,$value2,$value3,$lang=NULL){

if($lang){
       $newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'lang' => $lang
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
 }

redirect("controller/function/$value1/$value2/$value3", 'refresh');

}
```

Comment: in the first I do not need refresh.
and in the second 
I do not need to past $lang variable in every function
it must check example before URL class load...
and after check function it must send filtered url in Url class...
I think I need to create some core class witch will or=verride bootstrap function...
but I do not know hos...